# Swift 4 - UITableViewController hide delete button editingStyleForRowAt .delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view controller and I want the user to be able to delete an item, so I implemented this:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .delete
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        self.array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I hide the delete button and only show it if the user swipes the row?

This is what it looks like, does it matter if I am enabled sorting?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this instead of those three functions you tried:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
} 

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        self.array.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

**EDIT**:

After seeing your screenshot, I believe this is what you are trying to achieve. You are trying to enable deleting when an `editButton` is pressed, and then the delete icon appears. If so, please try this code.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var array = [1,2,3]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
         navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
        tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(array[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .delete
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //deleting logic
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you may consider implementing just a slide to delete animation, and the code is that before the **EDIT**.

Comment: @user979331 can you show the code where u enabled `editing`?

Comment: `self.tableView.isEditing = true`

Comment: Try removing self.tableView.isEditing = true